# FindViewById returns null (only one, inside OnCreate and after SetContentView)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to put in a toolbar created by myself a centrered title. It was working exactly as intended with a basic toolbar but for different purpose I had to switch to Android.Support.V7 and now it isn't working anymore due to a `FindViewById` returning `null` now

Here's my code: (working on Xamarin.Android)

**MainPage.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bitmap_homepage" />
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/ListSpaces"
            android:focusable="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**toolbarMain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/toolbarMain_Name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**MainPageActivity.cs**

```
public static string TitleFolder = "Welcome";

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainPage);

            //Put toolbar
            var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbarMain);
            var ToolTitle = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.toolbarMain_Name);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            ToolTitle.Text = TitleFolder;
            }
```

The error Visual Studio is giving me is

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

When looking at the variables, the program is finding all the ids in Ressource.Designer, but return null to `Tooltitle`but `toolbar` is absolutely okay.

Any ideas ? It's slowly driving me crazy since it was working perfectly fine on a standard toolbar...
Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I followed the one from Cody W. since I'll be using the toolbar for different Activities so it'll be cleaner for me. But your solution seemed a good way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the contentview to MainPage.xml, but toolbarMain_Name is not an element of that layout.  You will need to either add the textview to your MainPage.xml or replace your declaration of the Toolbar with an include statement.

```
<include layout="@layout/your_toolbar_layout_name"/>
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot ! 
I had the include tag on the first toolbar but I erased it while creating it again with AppCompat. I was following the official Xamarin doc but I guess I did it wrong while changing the code

Answer (score 1):

V7 support toolbar has different setup,  call :

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbarMain))
```

Go through https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up for details.

Comment: Wasn't exactly what I intended to resolve and your answer didn't seem to work on my side but thanks anyway